# putting the array data into separate variables

Tags: php

I am trying to put the array data into two separate variables. But not getting it. Here is my code

```
if($option_query->row['type'] == 'date') {
    $array1[0] = $option_value;

    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key = $value<br>";
    }
```

Now i am getting the result :

```
0 = 2013-05-05
0 = 2013-05-07
```

I want to put 1st date in a variable called `datestart` and 2nd date in to `dateend`. 
How can I achieve this?

output for var_dump(array1);

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '2013-05-05' (length=10)
array (size=2)
  0 => string '2013-05-05' (length=10)
  1 => string '2013-05-07' (length=10)
```

EDITED HERE (ADDING)

```
 if($option_query->row['type'] == 'date' )

                        {


$arr = array( //Assuming that this should be the map of your array
        array(
            $option_value
        ),
        array(
            $option_value
            //$option_value
        )
    );

   // var_dump($arr);

    echo $arr[1][0];
   echo $arr[1][1];

    }


                    }
```

I echoed like this and got the o/p

```
2013-05-20
2013-05-30
```

It works!!!!!

Comment: how do you have to keys zero in the same array?

Comment: then, how can i do it ? :(. is there any other way to do it?. $array1[] = $option_value; also works.

Comment: Please c&p the ouput of `var_dump($array1);` here.

Comment: Hi, i have pasted the var_dump result in the main question area

Comment: Then use the list() as proposed below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to loop, if you've an array like

```
$arr = array('1/2/2010', '2/2/2012');

$start_date = $arr[0]; //Assigning 1st index to this var
$end_date = $arr[1]; //Assigning 2nd index to this var
```

Update : Your array is a nested array, you need to use this

```
<?php
    $arr = array( //Assuming that this should be the map of your array
        array(
            '2013-05-05'
        ),
        array(
            '2013-05-05',
            '2013-05-07'
        )
    );

    var_dump($arr);

    echo $arr[1][0];
    echo $arr[1][1];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure *$array1* has two rows and that ones are the dates you need, you may look at the **list** builtin function :

```
list($start_date, $end_date) = $array1;
```

Comment: hey this works , but there is a small problem. I don't know whether its my mistake. If i echo $start_date, it give 1st date twice, but for $end_date it gives proper output

Comment: @user2316844 are you sure you've done nothing wrong when outputting!? or try `$array1[1]` instead of `$array1`.

Answer (score 2):

Are the dates in `$array1` sorted ascending? If not you should call `asort($array)` to sort it low-to-high.

```
if ($option_query->row['type'] == 'date') {
    $dates = $array1; // Keep $array1 in tact
    $datestart = array_shift($dates); // Shifts an element off the front of $dates 
    $dateend = array_pop($dates); // Pops an element off the end of $dates
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array['datestart'] = $option_value_start; 
$array['dateend'] = $option_value_end;
foreach ($array AS $k=>$v){
     $$k=$v;
}
echo $datestart; // print $option_value_start VALUE
echo $dateend;
```